# Delayed queue solution

Tags: mongodb, redis, queue, rabbitmq, rethinkdb

I'm looking for a delayed queue solution for my web app.

It should receive messages (ideally, via http keep-alive connections) and then make push requests (ideally, via http to the internal url) after predetermined for each message delay. Polling also considered, but not desirable.

Requirements: scaling, persistence, performance.

Does anyone know a ready solution that works out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

rabbitmq with the delayed-message exchange should do what you need

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange